# Where to place calculation logic in N-Tier C# application

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I am working on an N-Tier application in C# using the following application structure.

My Solution structure.

1. UI - WPF Prism and ViewModels connects to Services. Used by store employees.
2. Services - WCF - Business Logic, Data Retrieval and connection to DB through Data layer.
3. Entities - EF POCO Entities - No logic.
4. Data - EF DbContext and EDMX - DB connectivity
5. Web - ASP.NET MVC application - UI web based version with limited functionality and customer access. connects to Services.

I am wondering where to have the logic for an entity object that has calculations.

Here is the Sample entity.

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public Decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    public Decimal? SalesTax { get; set; }
    public Decimal? DiscountPercent { get; set; }
    public Decimal? DiscountAmount { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public ICollection<InvoiceDetail> InvoiceDetails { get; set; }

}

public class InvoiceDetail
{
    public int InvoiceDetailID { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }
    public Decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public Decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }

    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

}
```

In the above scenario, where should I place the logic to calculate total of the invoice when values change. For example, SalesTax getting updated will need to change the Invoice Total. Adding a line item to invoice needs to change subtotal, tax, discount and Total.

I was wondering if I can do it in the service layer and leave the Entity anemic. The concern I have is I need to constantly send the whole invoice object back and forth the wire.

Even though I am not doing a mobile solution yet, not sure if this is a good idea in a mobile environment which may consume data due to sending Invoice back and forth.

The other idea for example, I was thinking was to have AddLineItem() method in InvoiceDetail, and CalculateTotals() in Invoice.

AddLineItem automatically calculates total (This I may make it a computed column in DB) for line item and calculate subtotal, discount, tax, total for the invoice. I assume in this case I may have to remove the automatic properties if I want to call CalculateTotals() internally for example when the SalesTax changes instead of leaving it to the client to call CalculateChanges. Is that correct? If yes, this becomes a problem for me to refactor the EF template to not have automatic properties instead properties with backing fields.

Please advise which of the approach is better and why? Or a completely different approach for this scenario. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "an N-Tier application using WCF, EF, Web and WPF"  This is not very well defined.  One of your tiers is a presentation layer, and you have several versions of that?  One of your tiers is some sort of database you're connecting to with EF.  What other layers are in the middle?  What does your design say each layer is responsible for?

Comment: use a repository: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-2cplusdoneplusright

Comment: @DeniseSkidmore: I have updated the project structure and their responsibilities based on your question.

Comment: @Isak....was my below answer helpful?

Comment: You've answered your own question then, your design description says that business logic goes in the service layer.  If your design is concerning you about the amount of traffic generated between layers, consider breaking the service layer up into a service layer and a library.  The library could be used by any of the GUIs and contain some minor business logic that does not need to pass through the server but does need to be consistent between GUIs.  Be aware of the security concerns of placing critical logic on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had a smiliar issue in our tool and put the calculation in the Domain object itself.  The reason being that an object should know what it's total is because it knows about its children.  The Business Logic used in our Service layer was specific to business rules and not calculations.  Here's a sample of our code (note:  We are using C#.Net with MVC3):

```
public class Task : DomainBase
{
    public virtual ICollection<Subtask> Subtasks { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Subtask(s) Total Cost")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    //calculated property
    public virtual double TotalSubTaskCost
    {
        get
        {
            if (Subtasks == null)
                return 0;
            if (!Subtasks.Any())
                return 0;
            double it = Subtasks.Where(a => a != null).
                Aggregate<Subtask, double>
                    (0, (current, a) => current + a.TotalCost);
            return it;

        }

    }

 }
```

Whenever Task is queried for its TotalSubtaskCost, it performs the calculation.  Each Subtask has its own property , TotalCost.  So we Aggregate and Sum those values for the children Subtasks.  And since Task always knows about its own Subtasks, the Calculation should always be correct.

Comment: Yes. This is useful and helpful validating my thought. The only problem I will have will be EF POCO template to be rearranged to accommodate this. Not sure how much work this is.

Comment: I see comment in my inbox starting with "Personally I would probably not have the Total of subitems in the entity model, and instead have ..." but cant see that answer. Don't know whose answer it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: @Isak...I'm not familiar with POCO templates and how they're constructed or derived.

Comment: @Isak...yeah that answer was on your question for a few minutes, then it must've been deleted.  I didn't see who posted it...sorry

Comment: Thanks Mike. I did use this approach.